# Parse value of input field to query parameters

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Can I parse the value of an input field to a query parameter to get the values of a select field within the same form?

The code is following:

```
<FORM ACTION="login.php" METHOD=get>

    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" ><br>

    <label for="pin">Password: </label>
    <input id="pin" name="pin" type="password" ><br>

    <label for="company">Company</label>
            <select name="Company" id="company">
            <option>Select Company:</option>
            <?php
                $conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connet_error);
                }
                $email = isset($_GET['email'])?$_GET['email']:"";
                $sql="select company from accounts WHERE email = '$email';";
                $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if ($results->num_rows > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                        echo "<option value=\"company1\">" .$row['company'] . "</option>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </select>

    <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Login"></input><br>
    <a id="cust-nopin" href="javascript:;"><p class="text_centered_pass">Click here if you don't have a password</p></a>

</FORM>
```

Is that not possible?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can't understand you. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i want to use the value of input id="email" as a parameter for the query which will populate the select options for select id="company".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario your best bet would be Ajax.

Your Form Page:

```
<form action="login.php" method=get>

    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" ><br>

    <label for="pin">Password: </label>
    <input id="pin" name="pin" type="password" ><br>

    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <select name="Company" id="company">
        <option value="">Select Company:</option>
    </select>

    <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Login"></input><br>
    <a id="cust-nopin" href="javascript:void(0);"><p class="text_centered_pass">Click here if you don't have a password</p></a>

</form>
```

Now the JQuery Part:

```
$(function () {
        $(document).on("change, blur, keydown", "#email", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'path/to/ajaxfile.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {email: $(this).val()},
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                if (response.status) {
                    var html = '<option value="">Select Company:</option>' + response.html;
                    $("#company").html(html);
                } else {
                    console.log(status.message);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert("Something went wrong please try again later.");
                console.log(data.responseText);
            });

        });
    });
```

And then the path/to/ajaxfile.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connet_error);
}

if (! empty($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['email']);
    $sql = "SELECT company FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($results->num_rows > 0){
        $html = "";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $html .= '<option value="' . $row['company'] . '">' . $row['company'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo json_encode(array("status" => true, "html" => $html));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "There is no company with that email address."));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "No email is there to lookup."));
}
```

This should help you achieve what you are trying to do...

I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use an input field's value as a parameter for your query. It is a very common scenario.

Your query does not work because you have included the `$email` variable inside single quotes. So this should work:

```
$sql="select company from accounts WHERE email = $email";
```

(the semicolon at the end is not needed).

**BUT**

This way of using user input to query the database is a bad practice as it makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

To safeguard against SQL Injection it is recommended to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

So you should query the database like this:

```
$sql="select company from accounts WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment about the vulnerability. I will edit the way it is currently written.